# convert mixed text to UTF-8

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, binary

I would like to convert a string to UTF-8. The problem is that some letters consists of two octets binary code and most of it of one octet binary code.

Here is a example:

```
echo $title; #  Shuttle XPС slim C

echo Encoding::fixUTF8(Encoding::toUTF8($title)); #  Shuttle XP? slim C
```

Now if you convert the string to binary you can see that the question mark c character looks different in binary:

```
S = 01010011
h = 01101000
u = 01110101
t = 01110100
t = 01110100
l = 01101100
e = 01100101
  = 00100000
X = 01011000
P = 01010000
C = 11010000 10100001
  = 00100000
s = 01110011
l = 01101100
i = 01101001
m = 01101101
  = 00100000
C = 01000011
```

So the problem is that one 'C' is '11010000 10100001' and one 'C' is '01000011'. This happens to many different letters. Is there an way to fix that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out, it may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21322702/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-remove-utf-8s-right-to-left-override-characters

Comment: FYI: Functions like "`toUTF8`" without specifying *what from* and "`fixUTF8`" (what does that even mean?) are categorically nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your text is already UTF-8 encoded, that has nothing to do with the problem. The issue is that that "C" is actually "C", i.e. U+0421 CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER ES. It is the entirely wrong character which merely looks like a latin "C". You cannot fix that by encoding conversions, you need to fix that by replacing the letter with the actual one you need. This can be rather manual, unless you can come up with a list of characters to look out for and their replacement.

Answer (score -1):

Why manage two octets?, can try this;

> lower c = 01100011
>
> upper C = 01000011