# how to remove &rlm; and ascii character from string with php

Tags: php

i will sahre my problem and how it solved
my database sql

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.7.9
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Sep 07, 2020 at 07:54 AM
-- Server version: 10.1.31-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 5.6.34

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


CREATE TABLE `ddrugs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `multicodes` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



INSERT INTO `ddrugs` (`id`, `code`, `multicodes`) VALUES
(13916, '10013916', '6221075051207,10013916,6221075050750, 6221075051207‏');


ALTER TABLE `ddrugs`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);


ALTER TABLE `ddrugs`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=13917;
COMMIT;
```

i have items with multicodes in my database
before adding extra code to item i should check if exist or not
when i check it give not found  but in real it is found , after checking console i find `&rlm;` after code , this generated during editing and prevent matching

main problem come from encoding query result on utf8 and problem solved by this function convert_ascii ,

second mistake was that i try to replace `&rlm;` from whole filed multicodes without iteration but this not the main cause of trouble

my php code

```
function convert_ascii($string) 
{ 
    // Replace Single Curly Quotes
    $search[]  = chr(226).chr(128).chr(152);
    $replace[] = "'";
    $search[]  = chr(226).chr(128).chr(153);
    $replace[] = "'";
    
    // Replace Smart Double Curly Quotes
    $search[]  = chr(226).chr(128).chr(156);
    $replace[] = '"';
    $search[]  = chr(226).chr(128).chr(157);
    $replace[] = '"';
    
    // Replace En Dash
    $search[]  = chr(226).chr(128).chr(147);
    $replace[] = '--';
    
    // Replace Em Dash
    $search[]  = chr(226).chr(128).chr(148);
    $replace[] = '---';
    
    // Replace Bullet
    $search[]  = chr(226).chr(128).chr(162);
    $replace[] = '*';
    
    // Replace Middle Dot
    $search[]  = chr(194).chr(183);
    $replace[] = '*';

    // Apply Replacements
    $string = str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
    
    // Remove any non-ASCII Characters
    $string = preg_replace("/[^\x01-\x7F]/","", $string);
    
    return $string; 
}     
        

 


echo "<pre>";
error_reporting(1);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'egpharmacy');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `ddrugs` WHERE `id` = 13916;";
$results = $mysqli -> query($sql);
$result = $results->fetch_object();
echo "<input type='text'  value='$result->multicodes' style='width:600px;' /><br>";
$result->multicodes = array_unique(explode(',', $result->multicodes) );
$array = $result->multicodes ;
$array2 = [];
foreach($result->multicodes as $key => $val){
    $val = trim("$val") ;
    $val = str_replace('&rlm;' , '' , $val );
    $val = str_replace('?' , '' , $val );
    $val = convert_ascii($val)  ;
    echo var_dump((($val))) .'<br>';
    if(!in_array( $val , $array2 )){
        array_push($array2 , $val );
    }
    
}
print_r($array2);
```

i attach photo to show how it is showed in  console

[image]

Comment: have you considered using regular expressions?

Comment: What is the problem in using `str_replace()` to remove it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove part of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192170/how-to-remove-part-of-a-string)

Comment: show your code, the diamonds for `&`,`r`,`l` and `m` is more of a problem then simply removing it.. I've solved this in the past, maybe it's of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21322702/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-remove-utf-8s-right-to-left-override-characters

Comment: i share my code and how it solved , thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove it during output it.

e.g your array:

```
    // your array with &rlm;
    $myarray = array('63252523534','35235235235&rlm','35523525','325235235532&rlm','352523532');
    
    // create a new array
    $newarray = array();
    
    // foreach your array which contains &rlm; in elements.
    
    foreach ($myarray as $marr){
//remove &rlm; from your strings and add them to your new array
        $newarray[] = str_replace('&rlm;','',$marr);
    }
    // you have the new array without &rlm
    print_r($newarray);
```

The result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 63252523534
    [1] => 35235235235
    [2] => 35523525
    [3] => 325235235532
    [4] => 352523532
)
```

Comment: This rlm not visible in browser , it is generated during fetching results from databsse

Comment: what do you mean "not visible in browser"?

Comment: Okey. But how do you output them to browser? Because then you can do with it whatever you want before official output to user.

Comment: I try to trim and striptags and str_replace all of them not working – as main problem come from utf8 encoding of mysql connection and problem solved by function convert_ascii , very thanks for care